# Program execution hanging when trying to use fgetc() over a file stream returned by fdopen() function

Tags: process, pipe, c, posix, fifo

I'm making a program where I'm creating 3 sets of fifos (named pipes) to comunicate over processes, I have found where the execution is hanging but not why, and now I'm stuck.

I have identified that execution is hanging when using  `fgetc()` . The file stream passed to  `fgetc()`  is the FILE* returned by the  `fdopen()`  function. Here's the function that's failing, **SAMPLE 1**:

```
void mapear(int numProceso, int col, int val, char *signo)
{
  int ncol=0, fdSplit, fdBuf;
  char nombrePipe[10], cadenaLlave[10000], cadenaValor[10000], caracter;
  bool encontroCadena = false, yaEscribioValores = false, creado = false;
  FILE *ptrLectura, *ptrEscritura;

  sprintf(nombrePipe, "split%d", numProceso);
  fdSplit = open(nombrePipe, O_RDWR);
  if(fdSplit == -1)
    printf("\n[ERROR]-No se pudo abrir el pipe split, se volvera a tratar despues.\n");
  ptrLectura = fdopen(fdSplit, "r+");

  sprintf(nombrePipe, "buf%d", numProceso);
  fdBuf = open(nombrePipe, O_RDWR);
  if(fdBuf == -1)
    printf("\n[ERROR]-No se pudo abrir el pipe buf, se volvera a tratar despues.\n");

  while((caracter = fgetc(ptrLectura)) != EOF)
  {
    printf("REPITIENDO\n"); //DEBUG LINE 3: [NOT PRINTING ANYTHING] SHOWS THAT THE EXECUTION HANGS AFTER THE fgetc() CALL

    /*Print something to fdBuf pipe*/
  }
  fclose(ptrLectura);
  close(fdSplit);
  close(fdBuf);
}
```

The line who is suposed to print "REPITIENDO" is not being executed...so the execution is not even entering the while, because it hangs at the `fgetc()`.

I'm also posting the samples where i'm creating the fifos with `mkfifo()`. ***PS: those are the same fifos that are being open each time that `mapear()` is being called*** **SAMPLE2**:

```
////////----CREATING THE FIRST SET OF PIPES AND OPENING THEM TO WRITE SOME REGISTERS TO EACH ONE----///////////
    mode_t fifo_mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR;

    sprintf(nombrePipe, "split%d", cuentaArchivo);
    if(mkfifo(nombrePipe, fifo_mode) == -1)
      return -1;
  
      fd = open(nombrePipe, O_RDWR); 
      if(fd == -1)
        printf("\n[ERROR]-No se pudo abrir el pipe split, se volvera a tratar despues.\n");

    while (fgets(registro, sizeof registro, ptrLectura) != NULL) 
    {
      //IF THE DESIRED NUMBER OF REGISTERS PER PIPE IS REACHED THEN CLOSE THE CURRENT PIPE AND OPEN THE NEXT ONE
      if(cuentaRegistro == lineasPorArchivo) 
      {
        close(fd); 
        printf("Cerrando pipe %s\n", nombrePipe);//DEBUG LINE 1: SHOWS THAT THE N PIPE IS BEING CLOSED
        cuentaRegistro = 0;
        cuentaArchivo++;
        tieneHuerfana = false; 

        sprintf(nombrePipe, "split%d", cuentaArchivo);
        if(mkfifo(nombrePipe, fifo_mode) == -1)
          return -1;

        fd = open(nombrePipe, O_RDWR);
        if(fd == -1)
          printf("\n[ERROR]-No se pudo abrir el pipe split, se volvera a tratar despues.\n");                 
      }
      //WRITES REGISTER TO THE PIPE
      dprintf(fd,"%s", registro);
      cuentaRegistro++;
    }
    fclose(ptrLectura);
    close(fd);
    printf("Cerrando pipe %s\n", nombrePipe); //DEBUG LINE 2: SHOWS THAT THE LAST PIPE IS BEING CLOSED

    ////////----JUST CREATING THE SECOND SET OF PIPES----///////////
    for(i = 1; i <= nmappers; i++)
    {
      sprintf(nombrePipe, "buf%d", i);
      if(mkfifo(nombrePipe, fifo_mode) == -1)
        return -1;      
    }

    ////////----JUST CREATING THE THIRD SET OF PIPES----///////////
    for(i = 1; i <= nreducers; i++)
    {
      sprintf(nombrePipe, "output%d", i);
      if(mkfifo(nombrePipe, fifo_mode) == -1)
        return -1;      
    }
```

I will also give the sample where i'm calling the function `void mapear(int numProceso, int col, int val, char *signo)` **SAMPLE3**:

```
////////----CREATING THE CHILD PROCESSES THAT ARE GOING TO CALL mapear()----///////////

    pid_t mappers_pids[nmappers], reducers_pids[nreducers];

    for(i = 1; i <= nmappers; i++)
    {
      if((pid = fork()) == 0)
      {
        signal(SIGCONT, handle_sigcont);
        signal(SIGUSR1, handle_sigusr1);
        pause();
        mapear(i, col, val, signo); 
        kill(getppid, SIGCONT);
      }
      else if(pid < 0)
      {
        return -1;
      }
      //Padre
      mappers_pids[i] = pid;
    }
```

Finally, I will give the sample where the father process is sending the signals to it's childs so they could call `mapear()` **SAMPLE4**:

```
              ////////----FATHER SENDING SIGNALS TO IT'S CHILDS PROCESSES, SO THEY CAN CALL mapear()----///////////
              for(i = 1; i <= nmappers; i++)
              {
                kill(mappers_pids[i], SIGCONT);
                pause();
              }
```

In this last sample, besides of the fact that the father process is sending the signals to it's childs, the father process is also waiting in  `pause()`  until it receives a signal from the child that is currently executing  `mapear()`  function.

**PS: THE ORDER OF EXECUTION IS:

-SAMPLE2

-SAMPLE3

-SAMPLE4

-SAMPLE1 (Where I suppose the issue is)**

Thanks a lot, and I really hope that someone could help!

**UPDATE: I've been told to post a reproducible example so here it is:**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i, pid, col, val, lineas, nmappers, nreducers, intermedios, lineasPorArchivo, lineasHuerfanas, bufsPorProceso, bufsHuerfanos, cuentaBuf = 1, fd;
  int cuentaArchivo=1, cuentaRegistro=0;
  bool salir = false, tieneHuerfana = false;
  char *consulta = (char*) malloc(10);
  char *signo = (char*) malloc(2); 
  FILE *ptrLectura, *ptrEscritura;
  char registro[150], nombrePipe[10];

    lineas = 16;
    nmappers = 4;
    nreducers = 2;
    intermedios = 0;

    lineasPorArchivo = lineas/nmappers;
    lineasHuerfanas = lineas%nmappers;

    ptrLectura = fopen("log16","r");

    ////////----CREATING THE FIRST SET OF PIPES AND OPENING THEM TO WRITE SOME REGISTERS TO EACH ONE----///////////
    mode_t fifo_mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR;

    sprintf(nombrePipe, "split%d", cuentaArchivo);
    if(mkfifo(nombrePipe, fifo_mode) == -1)
      return -1;
  
      fd = open(nombrePipe, O_RDWR); 
      if(fd == -1)
        printf("\n[ERROR]-No se pudo abrir el pipe split, se volvera a tratar despues.\n");

    while (fgets(registro, sizeof registro, ptrLectura) != NULL) 
    {
      //IF THE DESIRED NUMBER OF REGISTERS PER PIPE IS REACHED THEN CLOSE THE CURRENT PIPE AND OPEN THE NEXT ONE
      if(cuentaRegistro == lineasPorArchivo) 
      {
        close(fd); 
        printf("Cerrando pipe %s\n", nombrePipe);//DEBUG LINE 1: SHOWS THAT THE N PIPE IS BEING CLOSED
        cuentaRegistro = 0;
        cuentaArchivo++;
        tieneHuerfana = false; 

        sprintf(nombrePipe, "split%d", cuentaArchivo);
        if(mkfifo(nombrePipe, fifo_mode) == -1)
          return -1;

        fd = open(nombrePipe, O_RDWR);
        if(fd == -1)
          printf("\n[ERROR]-No se pudo abrir el pipe split, se volvera a tratar despues.\n");                 
      }
      //WRITES REGISTER TO THE PIPE
      dprintf(fd,"%s\n", registro);
      cuentaRegistro++;
    }
    fclose(ptrLectura);
    close(fd);
    printf("Cerrando pipe %s\n", nombrePipe); //DEBUG LINE 2: SHOWS THAT THE LAST PIPE IS BEING CLOSED

    ////////----JUST CREATING THE SECOND SET OF PIPES----///////////
    for(i = 1; i <= nmappers; i++)
    {
      sprintf(nombrePipe, "buf%d", i);
      if(mkfifo(nombrePipe, fifo_mode) == -1)
        return -1;      
    }

    ////////----CREATING THE CHILD PROCESSES THAT ARE GOING TO CALL mapear()----///////////

    pid_t mappers_pids[nmappers], reducers_pids[nreducers];

    for(i = 1; i <= nmappers; i++)
    {
      if((pid = fork()) == 0)
      {
        signal(SIGCONT, handle_sigcont);
        signal(SIGUSR1, handle_sigusr1);
        pause();
        mapear(i, col, val, signo); 
        kill(getppid, SIGCONT);
      }
      else if(pid < 0)
      {
        return -1;
      }
      //Padre
      mappers_pids[i] = pid;
    }
    
    sprintf(consulta, "4,=,0");

    if(validarConsulta(consulta, &col, &val, &signo))
    {
      printf("\n[EN PROCESO]-Buscando registros de la columna %d que sean %s %d\n", col, signo, val);

      ////////----FATHER SENDING SIGNALS TO IT'S CHILDS PROCESSES, SO THEY CAN CALL mapear()----///////////
      for(i = 1; i <= nmappers; i++)
      {
        kill(mappers_pids[i], SIGCONT);
        pause();
      }

      printf("SUCCES!\n"); //EXECUTION SHOULD REACH THIS POINT WITHOUT HANGING 
    }
  return 0;
}

bool validarConsulta(char *consulta, int *col, int *val, char **signo)
{
  char *columna, *simbolo, *valor;

  columna = strtok(consulta, ",");
  *signo = strtok(NULL,",");
  valor = strtok(NULL,",");
  *col = atoi(columna);
  *val = atoi(valor);

  return (strcmp(*signo,"<") == 0 || strcmp(*signo,"<=") == 0  || strcmp(*signo,">") == 0 || strcmp(*signo,">=") == 0 || strcmp(*signo,"=") == 0);
}

void mapear(int numProceso, int col, int val, char *signo)
{
  int fdSplit, fdBuf, cont = 0;
  char nombrePipe[10], caracter;
  FILE *ptrLectura, *ptrEscritura;

  sprintf(nombrePipe, "split%d", numProceso);
  fdSplit = open(nombrePipe, O_RDWR);
  if(fdSplit == -1)
    printf("\n[ERROR]-No se pudo abrir el pipe split, se volvera a tratar despues.\n");
  ptrLectura = fdopen(fdSplit, "r+");

  sprintf(nombrePipe, "buf%d", numProceso);
  fdBuf = open(nombrePipe, O_RDWR);
  if(fdBuf == -1)
    printf("\n[ERROR]-No se pudo abrir el pipe buf, se volvera a tratar despues.\n");

  printf("STUCK JUST BEFORE THE WHILE\n");
  while((caracter = fgetc(ptrLectura)) != EOF)
  {
    printf("REPEATING %d\n", cont); //DEBUG LINE 3: [NOT PRINTING ANYTHING] SHOWS THAT THE EXECUTION HANGS AFTER THE fgetc() CALL
    cont++;
    /*Print something to fdBuf pipe*/
  }
  fclose(ptrLectura);
  close(fdSplit);
  close(fdBuf);
}

void handle_sigusr1(int sig)
{
  printf("\nˑMapper con PID[%d] culmina.\n", getpid());
  exit(0);
}

void handle_sigusr2(int sig)
{
  printf("\nˑReducer con PID[%d] culmina.\n", getpid());
  exit(0);
}

void handle_sigcont(int sig){
}
```

Now the execution is not even reaching the mapear() function call. The execution is still hanging, but now it hangs when sending de signal SIGCONT to the child processes.

PD: For the example to properly work you must locate a file called "log16" in the same folder where you will save the example code. The file should look like this:

```
   1        0     65 2592042    1     -1 1009884   -1     -1    -1  0   1  -1  -1  2  9 -1 -1
    2        0     71 2592046    1     -1 1010132   -1     -1    -1  0   1  -1  -1  2  9 -1 -1
    3       19     41 1893368    1     -1 1010108   -1     -1    -1  0   1  -1  -1  2  9 -1 -1
    4       19     42 1825976    1     -1  2172   -1     -1    -1  0   1  -1  -1  2  9 -1 -1
    5   516420     15 2592030    2     -1  4940   -1     -1    -1  0   2  -1  -1  1  8 -1 -1
    6  1284365     26 2012962    1     -1 14088   -1     -1    -1  1   3  -1  -1  1  8 -1 -1
    7  1284365     26 2290213    1     -1 13556   -1     -1    -1  1   3  -1  -1  1  8 -1 -1
    8  1284365     28 2058925    1     -1 14124   -1     -1    -1  1   3  -1  -1  1  8 -1 -1
    9  1284366     26 1782465    1     -1 14584   -1     -1    -1  1   3  -1  -1  1  8 -1 -1
   10  1284366     27 1831699    1     -1 14112   -1     -1    -1  1   3  -1  -1  1  8 -1 -1
   11  1389267    351 1573008    1     -1 351604   -1     -1    -1  0   4  -1  -1  1  8 -1 -1
   12  1389297    332 1572997    1     -1 351028   -1     -1    -1  0   4  -1  -1  1  8 -1 -1
   13  1477792      6 1484828    1     -1 351504   -1     -1    -1  0   4  -1  -1  1  8 -1 -1
   14  1480061     23 1482543    1     -1 352136   -1     -1    -1  0   4  -1  -1  1  8 -1 -1
   15  1666234     26 312610    1     -1 1690068   -1     -1    -1  0   5  -1  -1  2 11 -1 -1
   16  1669900      9 262547    1     -1 1558900   -1     -1    -1  0   5  -1  -1  2 11 -1 -1
```

Comment: I can't follow the code, but I understand fifos are line-buffered, and I don't see any "\n" in the writes. You might try flushing the outputs, or line-terminating them. Also, you are closing the fd, which would not flush the FILE* buffers.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant thanks for answering, your comment is helpful I did not even think of that before, I will add those '\n' and see if it fix my problem or at least if it changes something. But could you explain to me a little more the subject of which you're talking about? Why in C language when you're writing to screen or to a file people are frequently recomending to add a line ending character at the end of what you're writing? Also what do you mean with line buffered? (I've searched it on the internet but did not really understand what they're for)

Comment: [a] Try `man -s 3 setbuf` for a brief overview. Buffering is just an optimisation to reduce the number of physical transfers, and line buffering is a compromise between frequent user feedback and efficiency. [b] I never considered using a FILE* from a pipe fd -- I'm unclear how that buffering would work, but at a minimum I would flush the stream on every write. [c] you need caracter to be of type `int`: getc can return all 256 chars plus the constant EOF, so char is not wide enough.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant I have updated my code and now every time I write to the pipe i'm ending with a '\n', I don't know if you notice it but when writing to the pipe i'm not using write() i'm using fprintf() function, soo if it's really necessary to flush the stream I'm not be able to do it, or at least using fflush(), cause fflush takes a FILE* and not a file descriptor.

Comment: So EOF has not the size of a char?

Comment: @Paul_Pedant when you were talking about the fact that I was closing the fd in your first comment...I think it has something to do with the fact that the execution hangs at the start of the while loop. If I comment the lines of SAMPLE2 where I'm doing `close(fd)` and then compile and run, the execution will not hang at the start, but the while loop will be trigered way to many times.

Comment: The program should only print "REPITIENDO" 250 times, but the string is being printed more than 12000 times

Comment: @Paul_Pedant fifos are NOT line-buffered.

Comment: @Dacaramo without a reproducible example, it's very hard to guess what your problem is. But just in case: if you're assuming that the name/path of a named pipe is somehow magical, and you're always opening the same pipe via the same name, it's probably high time to give up on it ;-) Example -- the cat will only read the first `yeah`, the rest will go to a *different* fifo with the same name: `mkfifo f; while cat; do :; done <f & while echo yeah >f; do rm f; sleep 1; done`

Comment: @user414777 So what's de purpose of fifos AKA named pipes? Because if you're not able to open the same pipe via the same name as with normal files I think that call them named pipes is very missleading... Could you then explain to me how is the proper way of opening the same pipe with the same name? Thanks in advance

Comment: It's the same problem with normal files -- "names" are just directory entries, and a directory entry could be replaced with another one pointing to a different file while the original is still open by another process. But without a complete example, it's not clear what your problem is -- it may be that you're actually using stdio's fprintf instead of dprintf when writing to that pipe, and stdio streams are fully buffered by default (i.e. they're only flushed when the process exits or some amount of data, e.g. 4096 bytes has accumulated).

Comment: FWIW, If you're on Linux, you can use *abstract* unix-domain sockets as real "named" (not inode-bound) pipes between unrelated processes.

Comment: @user414777 Thanks for the information and for the help, I have added a reproducible example for you to try it if you willing to of course.

Comment: Did your compiler not warn you about `kill(getppid, SIGCONT)`? That's UB (On x86-64, it will probably try to send a random signal to some random process whose PID happens to be equal to the low bits of the address of the `getppid` function). But even if you fix that -- I don't see what calling `fork()` in a loop without ever exiting in the children is supposed to do. Create a fork-bomb, prevented by `pause()` not being ever interrupted ? ;-)

Comment: @user414777 is right -- I was tired last night. Pipes carry binary data (e.g. | gzip) so can contain any char value including "accidental" newlines. Of course, you can pass text delimited by \n for your own data flow, but the pipe won't know or care. It can therefore deliver part-lines, although it does guarantee "atomic" writes up to some limit (typically 4096 bytes). I would strongly recommend using the fd-based read() and write(), and never using FILE* with pipes, which can only confuse and delay the data.

Comment: @Dacaramo Yes, fgetc() returns int because char is not wide enough to accept EOF as well as all chars \000 to \377. Returned EOF gets truncated (usually to \377) and the compare with const EOF fails. In any case, you should use fd functions like read() and deal with as much data as you get in your own char array. It may contain the data from several writes, but for small transfers it will be a complete number of writes.

Comment: @Dacaramo Named pipes are complex. [A] If you make an app with some co-operating processes, then you probably want them to have unique pipe names so you can run more than one independent copy of the app: you don't want them cross-talking. [B] IIRC: If a named pipe has no writers, any readers get EOF and the whole app shuts down. Typically, a reader also keeps a write fd to its own input, because that keeps the pipe alive in case another writer shows up. When the reader wants to exit, it closes its write fd and gets EOF on its read fd, for a tidy closedown.

Comment: @Dacaramo Named pipes are also often transient. If a service is available, it can create its fifos to advertise that it is available, and remove them when it exits. Client programs can check if the service is available using the fifo name (with wildcards if it was made unique using e.g. the PID of the server), or even request to start the service. Having fifos left around can be a nuisance, and they are best kept in a separate directory: something like `grep re *` in a directory containing a fifo can either hang, or steal data from a running app.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Thanks a lot for your feedback, it made me realize that my code is just a completely mess. I realize that open a pipe for reading and writing in the same process it doesn't make even sence, also I have realized that I barely know something about OS and POSIX. Thanks a lot, I will need to do some big changes to my code in order to make it work as I expect.

Comment: @user414777 what do you mean with the fact that kill(getppid,SIGCONT) will try to send a random signal to some random process whose PID happens to be equal to the low bits of the address of the getppid function? I just want to send a signal to the parent process so the parent process will be able to continue it's execution, that's not the way to do it? should I be using getppid() instead of just getppid ? or is something else wrong? Sorry for the ignorance, is my first time working with all of this OS funcionalities, i'm just trying to aprove my OS college subject.

Comment: I always thought that the proper way to pass a function call to a function as an argument was indeed including the brackets as in every other programing language, but intelisense recomended to just let it without them. The compiler did not complain about it, maybe a warning or a note, but I did not realize because it wasn't an error. That's what you're talking about @user414777 ? Or some other thing?

Comment: You're not **calling** the `getppid` function. You're just passing its address to `kill`. The compiler would warn you about it -- don't ignore the warnings. You should've written `kill(getppid(), ...)` instead. But as I said, that's not the only problem -- you still have a lot of work to do ;-)

Comment: Allright, anyways it stills a really handy observation and I really think that what you're telling me will save me a lot of time later so I'll change it right now, thanks again.